# Inserting hyperlinks to web sites in captivate 6 with a variable

Tags: hyperlink, adobe-captivate

Hi want to insert a few hyperlinks in captivate 6 slides. However, while doing the development of the project, these links point to a test server. I would like to replace the base part of the hyperlinks , the www.abc.com part with the new destination address, once the project is to be final. Is there a way to use variable or some other method to do this in captivate , where I create part of  the hyperlink with a variable, and just by changing the variable value , have the hyperlink in all the slides change ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at a machine with Captivate installed so I can't verify this works, but if you put the base URL in a variable called base, you might be able to set the destination address to $$base$$/location/of/resource

For future reference, a fairly active forum for Captivate exists on Adobe's site [here](http://forums.adobe.com/community/adobe_captivate).